# SQL - Finding a teams current streak

Tags: sql

My table is as follows (filtered by HomeTeam):

```
Date       HomeTeam    AwayTeam    FTR
2017-08-14  Team A      Team B      A
2017-08-24  Team A      Team C      H
2017-08-28  Team A      Team D      D
2017-09-11  Team A      Team B      H
2017-09-25  Team A      Team D      H
```

Through searching, I've found plenty of examples that find the highest streaks at any point in the season. I'm looking for the current streak working back from the most recent date.

The result in this example would be:

```
HomeTeam   Streak

Team A     W2
```

Example 2:

```
Date       HomeTeam    AwayTeam    FTR
2017-08-14  Team B      Team A      A
2017-08-24  Team B      Team C      D
2017-08-28  Team B      Team D      H
2017-09-11  Team B      Team A      A
2017-09-25  Team B      Team D      A
```

```
HomeTeam      Streak

Team B         L2
```

Any help appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: 1. what is your rdbms? mysql? oracle? 2. what are the meaning of FTR values?

Comment: 1. mysql
2. H = Home Win, D = Tie, A = Away Win. As the example focuses on the Home Team, a group of H's would be a "W" streak, A's would be a "L" streak and would just leave D's as a "D" streak. hope that helps.

Comment: Presumably you want to include Away games in the streak as well as Home games?

Comment: Eventually, yes. I plan to separate by Home form, Away form and overall form. Was hoping to get a little help with the home only so I can attempt to figure out the rest. Thanks

Comment: Meant to take a look at this but got distracted by work. Did you ever get anywhere?

Comment: I got there in the end. I used the selected answer from the following: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/64727/get-streak-count-and-streak-type-from-win-loss-tie-data. Thanks